# Embed XSLT in a SOAP Request

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I'm using a software that imports an XML file into a workflow then exports it to a web service using workflow tasks.
The XML file is like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <NostroEvent>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <AccountNumber>123</AccountNumber>
      <Debit>100</Debit>
     </NostroEvent>
```

The file is imported and I'm writing the following SOAP request of the ExportWS task that would select all the tags of the xml and sends them to the web service: (the configuration of the connection to the web service is also entered in that task in another section)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <!--xsl:variable name="nostro">
     <xsl:copy-of select="NostroEvent"></xsl:copy-of>
     </xsl:variable-->
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bmt="http://bmt">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
      <bmt:insertNostro>
       <bmt:Xml><xsl:copy-of select="NostroEvent"/></bmt:Xml>
      </bmt:insertNostro>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that insertNostro is the web method and Xml is the parameter, to which I'm passing the set of tags and text starting from NostroEvent. But it's not working. I keep getting a null pointer exception meaning that the web service received a null string. I tried to use an xsl variable at the top but it was also useless.

Comment: I've ran this successfully, both using Saxon and Xalan. There seems to be nothing wrong with your XSLT.

Comment: I think the problem resides in the fact that my webservice expects a string Xml, and I'm passing to <bmt:Xml> a subtree with xsl:copy-of instead of a string. So that's why it's giving me the null pointer exception. But I don't know how to transform the return value of xsl:copy-of into a string

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that it is XML and not a string, Try doing something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bmt="http://bmt">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <bmt:insertNostro>
                <bmt:Xml>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="NostroEvent" mode="toString"/>
                </bmt:Xml>
            </bmt:insertNostro>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="toString">
    &lt;<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>&gt;<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" mode="toString"></xsl:apply-templates>&lt;<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> /&gt;
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Depending on which XSLT processor being used there may be a helper function to do this, such as saxon:serialize().

Comment: Is there a way to show the "<" and ">" as they are instead of &lt; and &gt;?

Comment: Yes, but that would make the output the same as it was.

Comment: I don't understand, you mean it'll always show the signs as &lt; and &gt; ? What can I try to get the actual signs?

Comment: Ultimately, XML is just text. It does not care about types. If you replace the &gt;/&lt; with >< it would give the same result as the solution that you wrote yourself in the question. It makes no difference if it is written by <xsl:copy/> or if you write the tags manually.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, you've lead me on the right track for the solution. I'm trying to just put < instead of &lt; and /> instead of &gt; but I'm getting errors. I'm trying this in a XSL editor without the soap because our system is down. I don't know if I won't be having errors once i try this (in the SOAP request) on our software.